# How to find those departments whose sum of employee's salary is greater than or equal to 10,000 in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the screenshot of the table and my attempt of this query

[image: Here is the screenshot of the table and my attempt of this query]

here's the query that I am running

```
SELECT department 
  FROM employees 
 where ( select sum(salary) 
            group 
        by department 
        having sum(salary) >=10000);
```

It returns 0 rows whereas it should return 'COE' as the sum of its employees is 14000

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want this:

```
select department
from employees
group by department
having sum(salary) >= 10000;
```